# How to make a delete button in controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

A little stomped here attempting to make a delete button in my spring-boot/hibernate/thymeleaf set up but have been unsuccessful. I'm not sure if it is something I am doing wrong in the controller or the view. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any insight.

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "toner_buyer")
public class Buyer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private Long buyerId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "BUYER_ADDRESS")
    private String buyerAddress;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = OrderForm.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "buyer")
    private List<OrderForm> orders;

    public Buyer(){}

    public Buyer(String firstName, String lastName, String buyerAddress, Set<Toner> buyerToner) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
    }

    public Long getBuyerId() {
        return buyerId;
    }

    public void setBuyerId(Long buyerId) {
        this.buyerId = buyerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getBuyerAddress() {
        return buyerAddress;
    }

    public void setBuyerAddress(String buyerAddress) {
        this.buyerAddress = buyerAddress;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class BuyerController {

    private BuyerService buyerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setBuyerService(BuyerService buyerService){
        this.buyerService = buyerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add-buyer")
    public String showBuyerPager(Model model){
        List<Buyer> buyers = buyerService.findAllBuyers();
        model.addAttribute("buyers", buyers);
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        return "add-buyer";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showBuyerForm")
    public String addBuyerForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        return "add-buyer";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addBuyer")
    public String postBuyerForm(@ModelAttribute("buyer") Buyer buyer, Model model){
        buyerService.saveBuyer(buyer);
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/deleteBuyer")
    public String deleteBuyer(@ModelAttribute("buyer") Buyer buyer, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("buyer", new Buyer());
        buyerService.deleteBuyer(buyer);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header> Welcome to Toner Stock </header>
<h1>Add Buyer</h1>
<div id="mynav" align="center">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="add-buyer">Add Buyer</a></li>
        <li><a href="add-manager">Add Manager</a></li>
        <li><a href="current-stock">Current Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="transactions">Transactions</a></li>
        <li><a href="orders">Order Form</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <div id="display-table" align="center">
       <form th:action="@{/addBuyer}" th:object="${buyer}" style="width:100%" method="post">
           <table>
               <td><label>First Name: </label></td>
               <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"/></td>
               <td><label>Last Name: </label></td>
               <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}"/></td>
               <td><label>Enter Address: </label></td>
               <td><input type="text" th:field="*{buyerAddress}"/></td>
               <td><input type="submit" value="save"/></td>
           </table>
       </form>
    </div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table id="info-table" align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="buyer : ${buyers}">
                <td th:text="${buyer.firstName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${buyer.lastName}"></td>
                <td th:text="${buyer.buyerAddress}"></td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/deleteBuyer}" th:object="${buyer}" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="${buyer}"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option th:each="buyer : ${buyers}"
                    th:text="${buyer.firstName}"
                    th:value="${buyer.buyerId}"
            ></option>
        </select>
    </div>
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Print Trace:

```
2017-05-21 12:07:11.791  INFO 562 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 562 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/TonerStock)
2017-05-21 12:07:11.794  INFO 562 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-21 12:07:12.055  INFO 562 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sun May 21 12:07:12 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-21 12:07:13.702  INFO 562 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$23cb376d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-05-21 12:07:14.133  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-21 12:07:14.154  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-05-21 12:07:14.155  INFO 562 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-05-21 12:07:14.295  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-05-21 12:07:14.295  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2245 ms
2017-05-21 12:07:14.503  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-05-21 12:07:14.509  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 12:07:14.510  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 12:07:14.510  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 12:07:14.510  INFO 562 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-05-21 12:07:15.412  INFO 562 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-21 12:07:15.448  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-05-21 12:07:15.576  INFO 562 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-05-21 12:07:15.578  INFO 562 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-05-21 12:07:15.769  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-05-21 12:07:15.902  INFO 562 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-05-21 12:07:17.162  INFO 562 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-21 12:07:18.093  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sun May 21 12:07:12 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-21 12:07:18.234  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/add-buyer]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.showBuyerPager(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.235  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/showBuyerForm],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.addBuyerForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.235  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/addBuyer],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.postBuyerForm(com.ronone.entities.Buyer,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.236  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/deleteBuyer],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.deleteBuyer(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.236  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.MainController.homepage()
2017-05-21 12:07:18.238  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/add-manager]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.showManagerPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.238  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/showManagerForm],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.addManagerForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.238  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/saveManager],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.postManagerForm(com.ronone.entities.Manager,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.239  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/deleteManager],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.ManagerController.deleteManager(com.ronone.entities.Manager,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.241  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/orders]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.OrderController.orderFormPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.241  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/orders],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.OrderController.selectOrder(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.241  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/saveOrder],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.OrderController.sendOrderToORM(com.ronone.entities.Toner,com.ronone.entities.Buyer,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.243  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/current-stock]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.StockController.showStockPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.244  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/showStockItem],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.StockController.addStockItem(com.ronone.entities.Toner,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.244  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/saveToner],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.StockController.saveStockItem(com.ronone.entities.Toner,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.245  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/transactions]}" onto public java.lang.String com.ronone.controller.TransController.showTransPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.249  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.249  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-05-21 12:07:18.327  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-21 12:07:18.327  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-21 12:07:18.401  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-05-21 12:07:19.222  INFO 562 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-21 12:07:19.307  INFO 562 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-05-21 12:07:19.314  INFO 562 --- [           main] com.ronone.Application                   : Started Application in 18.059 seconds (JVM running for 18.911)
2017-05-21 12:07:25.767  INFO 562 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-05-21 12:07:25.768  INFO 562 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-05-21 12:07:25.801  INFO 562 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 33 ms
2017-05-21 12:07:27.623  INFO 562 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2017-05-21 12:07:29.064 ERROR 562 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.delete(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ronone.service.BuyerService.deleteBuyer(BuyerService.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ronone.controller.BuyerController.deleteBuyer(BuyerController.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: What does it mean that you were unsuccessful? Any error, an exception, or it does not function as you expect? If the latter is true, then what do you expect and how does it function in reality?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy no exceptions but when I press the delete button on the app it doesn't work

Comment: Usually you only need an ID to delete an entity, and not the whole object (and you usually cannot pass the whole object in a single POST parameter). Try `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>` instead of `<input type="hidden" th:field="${buyer}"/>`, if your `Buyer` has `id` property; if not, add it; accept that ID in your controller and delete by it.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Thank you for the advice. I do already have an id property in the Buyer class but regarding my controller would I have to change the perimeters? I asked because I still got an exception.

Comment: What exception do you have? Please post the stacktrace in the body of your question.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy added

Comment: You have set an unsaved buyer object which doesn't have an id. I assumed showBuyerForm is the path to load the initial page, at that point forms are bound with new Buyer() object.

Comment: @RonPitt - can you open the developer console in the browser and see the payload you send in the POST request? And put it here, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only need an ID to delete an entity, and not the whole object (and you usually cannot pass the whole object in a single POST parameter).

Supposing that your `Buyer` class has `id` property (i.e. a pair of `getId()`/`setId(long)` methods, you could try to put

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${buyer}"/>
```

Also, you'll have to change your handler method like this:

```
@PostMapping("/deleteBuyer")
public String deleteBuyer(@RequestParameter("id") long buyerId) {
    buyerService.deleteBuyer(buyerId);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and also change your `BuyerService#deleteBuyer()` method to accept `long` (buyer ID) instead of a `Buyer` instance and delete it using that ID.